# How to call a field method using reflection

Tags: go, reflect

I have a lot of struct like this, with diff fields but have common field: fn func()

```
type a struct{
    // ....
    fn func()
}
```

what I want is call diff structs' instance's fn function, how to implement it；no use receiver func to implement, and the fn not exported

```
func call(i interface{}){
    // TODO
    // how to use reflect to call fn func
}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of different structs containing functions of the same signature, maybe you should refactor those functions as methods, and then create an interface that captures the behavior.  Then you won't need reflect at all.  Remember, the empty interface carries no information.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using a dynamic assignment to function then you can go about using interfaces; you can also create logic that interface method calls the struct field method; **I would recommend using methods and interfaces**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
}

type myInterface interface {
    fn()
}

func (a *A) fn(){
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

func main() {
    var i myInterface
    i = &A{}
    call(i)
}

func call(input myInterface) {
    input.fn()
}
```

**But** If you want to call field method using reflection you can go doing something like this; But the field `Fn` needs to be exported

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    Fn func()
}

func main() {
    a := A{func() { fmt.Println("Hello!!!") }}
    call(a)
}

func call(i interface{}) {
    valOf := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    valOf.FieldByName("Fn").Call([]reflect.Value{})
}
```